# Good idea to always reinitialize PrintWriter without closing?

Tags: java, process, io, java.util.scanner, printwriter

The following method always creates a new PrintWriter after each print:

```
public class ConsoleInput implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String msg = scan.nextLine();
            PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(App.serverProcess.getOutputStream()));
            w.println(msg);
            w.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem: The `serverProcess` sometimes gets refreshed, so I cannot initialize the `PrintWriter` before the infinite-loop, because it won't be able to point to the new `serverProcess` object then.

Is there any fix to that? Or is this common practice? What happens if the garbage collector cleans the old printwriters? Will it call "close" and mess up my app?

**UPDATE:**
The following code is extremely ugly, but it reduces the garbage-objects.

```
public class ConsoleInput implements Runnable {

    Process sProcess;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.sProcess = App.serverProcess;
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(App.serverProcess.getOutputStream()));
        while (true) {
            String msg = scan.nextLine();
            if (!sProcess.equals(App.serverProcess)) {
                sProcess = App.serverProcess;
                w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(App.serverProcess.getOutputStream()));
            }
            w.println(msg);
            w.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would call `close()` mess up your app? And you're not closing your `PrintWriter` which is a resource leak.

Comment: `close` would shut down the process if I'm not mistaken. At least it closes the outputstream forever.

Comment: @TrudleR, why don't you use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) ensuring that, every time you get `serverProcess`'s output stream, it is available?

Comment: @aribeiro I don't understand how this could change the situation?

Comment: @TrudleR, it would close the existing streams forcing you to create new streams on every loop, even if `serverProcess` hasn't changed. But definitely that's not a good approach... Perhaps using the alternative pointed out by @Joni, creating new streams per `serverProcess` change, is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector will not close PrintWriters automatically, so you're safe from that. Also, PrintWriter and OutputStreamWriters don't hold system resources, so you're safe from resource leaks. This program will work correctly, though it will generate garbage for the GC to deal with.

There is something to keep in mind though. If `serverProcess` gets refreshed after the `PrintWriter` is created but before the message is flushed, the message may be written to the output stream of the old `serverProcess`. If the old output stream is closed by the time this happens, you may get an `IOException`.

You need to synchronize this loop with whatever refreshes `serverProcess` so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: You are right, this is no atomic sequence. This won't be a problem according to my usecase though, but I will fix that. Do you have an idea how to do not create needless garbage?

Comment: The PrintWriter needs to be recreated only when `serverProcess` is refreshed. Can you get a callback that tells you when it happens? If not, is there a way to check within the existing loop if the refresh has happened?

Comment: @Joni, do mind elaborating on why *PrintWriter and OutputStreamWriters don't hold system resources, so you're safe from resource leaks*? Because one usually does `printWriter.close()` to free any system resources associated with it.

Comment: @aribeiro PrintWriter and OutputStreamWriter wrap other streams that may hold resources such as open file descriptors, but they themselves hold none. Calling `close` on them closes the wrapped stream, and this frees the resource. It's unnecessary (and potentially harmful) if the resource lifetime is managed by something else.

Comment: @Joni, got it! Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: @Joni: What do you say to my updated question? Is this what you thought of? Closing the `PrintWriter`on that object is already done as far as I know. EDIT: serverProcess is volatile. That still does not make it atomic, but the equals check will be far more accurate.

Comment: that should work, as long as you can trust your `equals` method to detect the process refresh... Before doing this that make sure that the extra memory pressure is causing a problem though, no point in trying to optimize something that doesn't have to be optimized